# Facebook login redirects to blank page

Tags: facebook, magento, facebook-login

I have integrated Facebook login into my website.

This is the code that I used:-

```
<a rel="facebook-connect" title="Facebook Connect" href="http://www.mysite.com/index.php/facebook/customer_account/connect/"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flogin.png') ?>" /></a>
```

It works fine when I tried it in localhost by replacing `href="http://localhost/magento/index.php/facebook/customer_account/connect/"`

But when I integrated it in the live website, it redirects me to a blank page with the url below:-

```
www.mysite.com/index.php/facebook/customer_account/connect/
```

After that nothing happens.Is this issue is related with above url or site url or anything other?

My app settings are:-

- Site URL    :- `http://www.mysite.com/`
- Site Domain :- `mysite.com`

Comment: What is `<a rel="facebook-connect"`? Who processes it?

Comment: i didn't understand your question? would you please elaborate it?

Comment: somethins is missing here..sorry for that..i m updating that.

Comment: yes. So you've put the link `<a rel="facebook-connect" ...` who and how processes the click handler? This code itself wouldn't connect user to facebook automagically

Comment: actually i m using magento.And i installed an facebook login magento extension.It works fine in locahost. Is there anything wrong in the url for the live website?